# How to write sql Native Query in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
"SELECT ColumnName, COUNT(*) FROM xyz GROUP BY ColumnName")
.addEntity(xyz.class);
return query.list();
```

but its showing me a error At session (**session can not be resolved**)
I will be thankful if anyone can help me executing this query.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to come from your SQL query but from your Hibernate Session. How do you create/initialize it and what is the exact error ?

Comment: its showing a red color underline on a word session and a cross mark if you look parallel to the left side which tells you session can not be resolved.

Comment: You mean it's a compilation error raised by Eclipse ? Did you at least create the session variable ?

Comment: Is it a **hibernate session object**? see in your import statement.

Comment: String queryString = "SELECT COUNT(columnName) FROM xyz GROUP BY columnName";
Query queryObject = getSession().createQuery(queryString);
return queryObject.list(); It work like this but i want to use SQL Native Query in Hibernate

Comment: but when i try to execute  "SELECT ColumnName, COUNT(columnName) FROM xyz GROUP BY columnName"; then its not letting me to execute it that why i wanted use native SQlQuery  I hope you understand what I'm asking for

Answer (score 0):

It seems your Session object not declared .

Check the imports also:

```
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Session;
```

Typical Hibernate Session code:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

Then  use your code :

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
"SELECT ColumnName, COUNT(*) FROM xyz GROUP BY ColumnName")
.addEntity(xyz.class);
return query.list();
```

Comment: Yes Errors are removed you are correct but still unable to execute query its Giving a error on console org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

Comment: I will be thankful to you if you can guide me what should i mention in .addEntity(xyz.class); // It should be the Getter and setter class or somethiing else.

Comment: Can you tell what you given at ColumnName??  its a property in XYZ class or sql column name ??

Comment: Yes XYZ is an getter setter class .in java its called as POJO.

Comment: ColumnName is a SQL column name and xyz is class where i have define getters and setters for the table

Comment: So that is causing exception ..Change that to the property name of XYZ

Comment: I changes it to the Property name of XYZ but still getting an error in the console SEVERE: Table 'DBName.XYZ' doesn't exist                    org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

Comment: try like my example SELECT user_name, COUNT(*) FROM user_master GROUP BY user_name.
where user_name is mapped column of username property in USER pojo  and user_master is the mapped table in DB to the USER pojo

Comment: yes If I'm not wrong I'm trying the same my ColumnName is mapped column of ColumnName property in Column pojo and XYZ is a mapped table in DB to the Column pojo. then why its shwing an error DBName.XYZ Does Not Exist.